# Vue.js unit test child emit calls parent function

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js

I am a little puzzled I am trying to unit test a child (ratingsItem component) emitting to a parent component. Here is the test code:

```
it("rating component should emit call to parent updateRating function", () => {
    const wrapper = factory({});
    const ratingComp = wrapper.find({ref: "ratings"});
    ratingComp.vm.$emit("updateRating", 1);
    expect(wrapper.emitted().updateRating).toEqual(1);
    expect((wrapper.vm as any).updateRating).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This is the code inside the parent component. You can see the ratingsItem component inside it:

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <div class="overlay" v-show="isModalOpen" @click="closeModal"></div>

        <div ref="modal" class="modal" v-show="isModalOpen">
          <div slot="header" class="modal_header">
            <div class="modal_header_title">{{headerTitle}}</div>
            <div @click="closeModal" class="modal_header_close">
              <img src="../assets/modal_close_icon.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>Restaurant Rating</label>
            <!-- rating component -->
            <ratingsItem ref="ratings" :rating="rating" :starSizePerc="12" @updateRating="updateRating"></ratingsItem>
          </div> 

          <!-- footer -->
          <button class="pointer cancel_btn" @click="closeModal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="pointer space_left save_btn" @click="submitDetails()">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

But when I run the test I get this error:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: undefined

      71 |   
      72 | 
    > 73 |     expect(wrapper.emitted().updateRating).toEqual(1);
         |                                            ^
      74 |     // expect((wrapper.vm as any).updateRating).toHaveBeenCalled();
      75 |   });
      76 | });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I checked `vue-test-utils` docs for 'emitted':
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/emitted.html

Can you try to wrap it in `vm.$nextTick`:

```
it("rating component should emit call to parent updateRating function", (done) => {
    const wrapper = factory({});
    const ratingComp = wrapper.find({ref: "ratings"});
    ratingComp.vm.$emit("updateRating", 1);
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(() => {
       expect(wrapper.emitted().updateRating).toEqual(1);
       expect((wrapper.vm as any).updateRating).toHaveBeenCalled();
       done()
    })
  });
```

Comment: Hi Amaj,Thanks for your response but that did not work. I have console.log(wrapper.find({ ref: "ratings" }).emitted()) which is the ratingsItem and it is definitely emitting as you can see from the console output:    `● Console

      [Object: null prototype] { updateRating: [ [ 1 ] ] }`

Comment: Where and what did you `console.log`?

Comment: `it("rating  component should emit call to parent updateRating function", () => {

    const wrapper = factory({});

    (wrapper.vm as any).isModalOpen = true;

    const ratingComp = wrapper.find({ ref: "ratings" }); 
    ratingComp.vm.$emit("updateRating", 1); console.log(wrapper.find({ ref: "ratings" }).emitted());

    expect(wrapper.emitted().updateRating).toEqual(1);
    expect((wrapper.vm as any).updateRating).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });`

Comment: Can you share your `factory` method in the main post? Also, it would be nice to have a case that I can run somewhere.

Comment: Here you go: `const factory = (propsData: object) => {
  return shallowMount(Home, {
    propsData: {
      ...propsData
    },
    stubs: {},
    mocks: {}
  });
};`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out this is what I used below:

```
it("rating  component should emit call to parent updateRating function", () => {
    const wrapper = factory({});
    const updateRating = jest.fn();
    wrapper.setMethods({ updateRating });
    wrapper.find({ ref: "ratings" }).vm.$emit("updateRating", { idx: 9 });
    expect(updateRating).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(updateRating).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ idx: 9 });
  });
```

Thanks for your help with this :)